# Syntax Error: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Tags: java, android, constructor

I am creating a navigations app to the application settings.
For that I am creating the following code, but, as I mention above in Title, I am getting a Syntax Error.
Kindly Guide me through this problem.

here is my **MainActivity.Java**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public MainActivity() {

    }

    private boolean MyStartActivity(Intent intent) {
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activitynotfoundexception) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean isAppInstalled(String s) {
        PackageManager packagemanager = getPackageManager();

        try {
            packagemanager.getPackageInfo(s, 128);
        } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException namenotfoundexception) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(0x7f030000);

        if (getIntent().getIntExtra("reload", 0) == 1) {
            if (isAppInstalled("com.sample.test")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.sample.test"));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Not Instaled", 0).show();
            }
        }

        ((Button)findViewById(0x7f080000)).setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            final MainActivity this$0;

            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isAppInstalled("com.sample.test")) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
                    intent1.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                    intent1.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.sample.test"));
                    startActivity(intent1);

                    return;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Not Instaled", 0).show();

                    return;
                }
            }

            {
                this$0 = MainActivity.this;
                super(); //Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That will be automatically be done by the compiler while generating the inner class.

Comment: Remove the empty contructor `MainActivity(){}` and **what the hell is `final MainActivity this$0;`? and `this$0 = MainActivity.this;`** And this is **insane**: `setContentView(0x7f030000);` (you should use R.layout.your_layout_name, instead). This is also harmful: `super(); //Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor`

Comment: Trying to get to the settings of a game @ Rohit Jain,
Thank You @BobMalooga

Comment: @JaiSharma Just remove that initializer block that is giving you the error. That is simply redundant there. Also, remove the variable `this$0`.

Comment: Okay got it sir @RohitJain

Comment: @BobMalooga While your advice is sound, I'm not sure your tone is really that friendly to a new programmer.

Comment: I'm just showing the errors he's done. Why should I be unfriendly?

Comment: @BobMalooga Perhaps it's just my interpretation. But if someone looked at something I did for the first time and peppered their response with "**What the hell is this?**" "**This is sheer madness!!**" etc., it's a little demeaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an anonymous inner class:

```
new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    // code exists here

    super();
}
```

and at the bottom of that class you call `super();` which is the super constructor call. This call must be the first one, but in your case is totally unnecessary. Just remove it.

Comment: `super()` cannot exist *anywhere* in an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the reason why this code doesn't compile isn't because you've placed `super()` at the *wrong place* in your anonymous class. It's because anonymous classes [**can't have an explicitly declared constructor**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1), at all.

There is nowhere you call call `super()` within an anonymous class without a compiler error.

The other answers are correct in pointing out it would be redundant anyway, even if it were possible.